# React useState() breaks unrelated components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gsap

I have a component that renders an infinite animation (with gsap), everything worked fine until I introduce a state to the parent component (App) I'm not passing a prop to the child component but as soon as the state changes my animation stops, I'm not getting any errors or warnings.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/bold-hamilton-5cncgv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: The issue is your `{<SectionList />}`. 1st - u don't need `{}` for a component. 2 When this component gets re-rendered, gasp loses its target to apply the animation to. 3 why are you creating a component inside of a component? the point of a component is to make em reusable. So either a) extract that `SectionList` component to its own component with the useEffect dedicated for it. or b) change the `SectionList` into a function that returns the value and use it as a constant (example: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-bhabha-mw4wlj?file=/src/MovingBanner.js )

Comment: Thanks @Lith, right on point, gsap loses it's target and thanks for pointing out my component inside a component.